# How to add class name dynamically in react JS on selected tab

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm trying to change the background color of selected tab. Problem is that I have to add dynamic class in dynamic Data.

I try to add css class in my code  But this css will selected My all Tabs

```
{emailActivities.map((activity, i) => {
    return (
        <li
        key={i}
        className={this.state.reportView === false ? "active" : null}
        onClick={() => {

            this.setState({ reportView: false }, this.getReportByActivityId(activity.activityId))
        }}
        >
        {activity.activityTitle}

        </li>   

        )
    })
}
```

This code will selected my all values by defalut
I Want to highlighted Selected Tab only. How to do this.

Comment: reportView default value is true

Comment: You should create a new component of each `li` element. By doing this only you can maintain state of each tab

Comment: so there is no option to do this with one li tag???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `activityId` to check the selected tab.

```
{
  emailActivities.map((activity, i) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={i}
        className={this.state.activeTab === activity.activityId ? 'active' : null}
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState(
            { reportView: false, activeTab: activity.activityId },
            this.getReportByActivityId(activity.activityId)
          );
        }}
      >
        {activity.activityTitle}
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `reportView: false`, you need a state for `activeTabName`.

1. Maintain state value

```
    this.state= {activeTabName:'set first tab name here for by default active'}
```

2. Add dynamic class `active` like this,

```
    {emailActivities.map((activity, i) => {
        return (
            <li
            key={i}
            className={this.state.activeTabName=== activity.activityTitle? "active" : null}
            onClick={() => {

                this.setState({ activeTabName: activity.activityTitle}, this.getReportByActivityId(activity.activityId))
            }}
            >
            {activity.activityTitle}

            </li>   

            )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of tabs is **fixed**, it can be realized by using the key value of map function. Or if there's a unique key in each object such as `activityId` in your codes, it is easy to do that. In this case, I think `reportView` state value is useless.

```
// initialize state
this.state={
    activeTabId: -1, //if you need to select one tab, you can init it by that's activityId
}
...
{emailActivities.map((activity, i) => {
    return (
        <li
        key={i}
        className={activity.activityId === this.state.activeTabId ? "active" : null}
        onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ activeTabId: activity.activityId };
            this.getReportByActivityId(activity.activityId));
        }}
        >
        {activity.activityTitle}

        </li>   

        )
    })
}
```

You can select the first tab by using `key` easily, if the number of tabs is **fixed**.

```
// initialize state
this.state={
    activeTabId: 0, // Select first tab.
}
...
{emailActivities.map((activity, key) => {
    return (
        <li
        key={key}
        className={key === this.state.activeTabId ? "active" : null}
        onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ activeTabId: key };
            this.getReportByActivityId(activity.activityId));
        }}
        >
        {activity.activityTitle}

        </li>   

        )
    })
}
```

Better yet, use `styled-component` rather than changing `className`.
For more details, please check.
[React Styled Components Tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-styled-components/)
[Styled Components Documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs)